# Cannot show paged table view to when adding text dynamically to a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, ecmascript-6

I am trying to build an application where the user can input text from a textbox and the text will append to dynamically generated table. The table will also have [Bootstrap Pagination](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_pagination.asp), where I only want to show 5 table rows per table view.

> The problem I'm facing is, whenever I load text from input textbox it
>   should go to the particular view of table. But when I am adding text
>   from textbox its coming in the first view by default. *(See screenshot
>   below)*

---

## Before:

[image]

## After:

[image]

---

### Here's the code snippet I'm working on

```js
$(function() {

  $("#myInput").keyup(function(event) {
    //On carriage return append the text to the table
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
      let text = $('#myInput').val();
      if (text != "") {
        let markup = `<tr><td>${text}</td></tr>`;
        $("#tblText tbody").append(markup);
        $('#myInput').val('');

        //Check if it is a multiple of 5?
        paginateTable();
      }
    }
  });



  function paginateTable() {
    $('#paginationDiv').html('<div class="container"><ul class="pagination pagination-lg" id="pagedText"></ul></div>');
    let rowsShown = 5;
    let totalRows = $('#tblText tbody tr').length;
    let numPages = totalRows / rowsShown;
    for (let i = 0; i < numPages; i++) {
      let pageNum = i + 1;
      $('#pagedText').append(`<li><a href="#" rel="${i}" class="pagedLink">${pageNum}</a></li>`);
    }
    $('#tblText tbody tr').hide();
    $('#tblText tbody tr').slice(0, rowsShown).show();
    $('#pagedText a:first').addClass('active');
    $(document).on('click', '.pagedLink', function(e) {
      debugger;
      $('.pagedLink').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
      let currentPage = parseInt($(this).attr('rel'));
      let startItem = currentPage * rowsShown;
      let endItem = startItem + rowsShown;
      $('#tblText tbody tr').css('opacity', '0.0').hide().slice(startItem, endItem).css('display', 'table-row').animate({
        opacity: 1
      }, 300);
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <input class="form-control input-lg" type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Enter text" />

  <table id="tblText" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-responsive">
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <div id="paginationDiv">
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

---

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5L4waLx6/18/) to my solution.

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: I think everything is functioning as it should, you are appending a new item at the end of your list, so it then becomes the first element on page 2 of your pagination table view. If you want the item just added to appear in the table view, you would need to prepend the item to your list, or if the item is part of page 2, cause your table view to re-render page 2 instead of page 1 or increase the number of viewable items in a page.

Comment: @RyanWilson I want to render page 2 on entering the 6th row automatically, but its coming back to page 1 on entering 6th row.

Comment: I think your problem is your division here: let numPages = totalRows / rowsShown; Since you have 6 rows / 5 to show you get 1, use modulus operator to see if you have a remainder and if so add 1 to numPages. Posting answer below to show what I mean.

Comment: @RyanWilson but how does that render the 2nd page?

Comment: @Once you know if you need page 1 or page 2 to render, trigger a click event on that page number.

Comment: No it should automatically route to page 2 when I am entering the 6th row and beyond.

Comment: Check my answer below.

Comment: My example was wrong, I'm working on your fiddle. One minute.

Comment: @RyanWilson any clue?

Comment: Got it, I had to use a promise to wait until your paginateTable() had resolved, then trigger click. Fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/5L4waLx6/59/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a promise to resolve your call to paginateTable() after it resolves in the promise.then() trigger click on last page of pagination to show newest item:

```
$(function(){

 $( "#myInput" ).keyup(function ( event )
  {
        //On carriage return append the utterance to the table
        if ( event.keyCode === 13 )
        {
            let text = $( '#myInput' ).val();
            if ( text != "" )
            {
              let markup = `<tr><td>${text}</td></tr>`;
              $( "#tblText tbody" ).append( markup );
              $( '#myInput' ).val('');

              //Check if it is a multiple of 5?
              //Create promise object to resolve paginateTable() and .then() of promise to trigger click event of last page in pagination
              var promiseToNewPage = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
                resolve(paginateTable());
              });
              promiseToNewPage.then(function(){
                    DisplayNewestPage();
              });
            }
        }
    });



   function paginateTable()
    {
        $( '#paginationDiv' ).html( '<div class="container"><ul class="pagination pagination-lg" id="pagedText"></ul></div>' );
        let rowsShown = 5;
        let totalRows = $('#tblText tbody tr').length;
        let numPages = totalRows / rowsShown;
        for (let i = 0; i < numPages; i++)
        {
            let pageNum = i + 1;
            $( '#pagedText' ).append( `<li><a href="#" rel="${i}" class="pagedLink">${pageNum}</a></li>`);
        }
        $( '#tblText tbody tr' ).hide();
        $( '#tblText tbody tr' ).slice(0, rowsShown).show();
        $( '#pagedText a:first' ).addClass('active');
        $( document ).on('click', '.pagedLink', function (e)
        {
            debugger;
            $('.pagedLink').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
            let currentPage = parseInt($(this).attr('rel'));
            let startItem = currentPage * rowsShown;
            let endItem = startItem + rowsShown;
            $( '#tblText tbody tr' ).css( 'opacity', '0.0' ).hide().slice( startItem, endItem ).css( 'display', 'table-row').animate({opacity: 1}, 300);
        });
    }
});
//Triggers click on last pagedLink class item
function DisplayNewestPage(){
    $('.pagedLink').last().trigger('click');
}
```

Comment: But it's not automatically routing to the 2nd page unless I manually click on the link corresponding to page 2.

Comment: Can you comment as to why the "promisified" solution works in detail in your answer?

Comment: @KunalMukherjee I added a comment in the code above to explain what is happening. The promise object .then() fires off after paginateTable() resolves, and calls the function DisplayNewestPage(). Here is a link that explains Promise in more depth (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)

Comment: that was a very clever solution `//Triggers click on last pagedLink class item
function DisplayNewestPage(){
    $('.pagedLink').last().trigger('click');
}` and `promiseToNewPage.then(function(){
                    DisplayNewestPage();
              });`