# jquery - Implementing pagination on dynamic data got from ajax in "div" tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination, bootstrap-4

I want to implement pagination for the result I get from an ajax request. The result is stored in multiple "div" tags arranged in the form of rows and columns. I read an answer that suggests using "DataTable" but I don't know if that library would work on divs

Below is my jquery code that creates div tags

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/listProducts",
        success: createGrid,
        error: function (data) {
            alert("Error Occured")
        }
    })
})

function createGrid(data)
{
    var main = $('#main')
    var rows = data.length/3
    var index = 0
    var navigation = $('#navigation')

    for(var rowIterator = 0; rowIterator < rows; rowIterator++)
    {
        var row = $(document.createElement("div")).addClass("agile_top_brands_grids");
        for(var columnIterator = 0; columnIterator<3; columnIterator++)
        {
            if(data[index]!==undefined)
            {
                var column = '<div class="col-md-4 top_brand_left"><div class="hover14 column"><div class="agile_top_brand_left_grid"><div class="agile_top_brand_left_grid_pos"> <img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/images/offer.png" alt=" " class="img-responsive"></div><div class="agile_top_brand_left_grid1"> <figure><div class="snipcart-item block"><div class="snipcart-thumb"> <a href="single.html"><img title=" " alt=" " src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/product-images/'+data[index].id+'.jpg" style="height:150px; width=150px;"></a><p>'+data[index].productName+'</p><h4>&#8377; '+data[index].price+' <span>$55.00</span></h4></div><div class="snipcart-details top_brand_home_details"><form action="#" method="post"><fieldset> <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart"> <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1"> <input type="hidden" name="business" value=" "> <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="'+data[index].productName+'"> <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="'+data[index].productName+'"> <input type="hidden" name="discount_amount" value="1.00"> <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="INR"> <input type="hidden" name="return" value=" "> <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value=" "> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add to cart" class="button"></fieldset></form></div></div> </figure></div></div></div></div>'
                row.append(column)
                index++;
            }
        }
        row.append('<div class="clearfix"></div>');
        row.insertBefore(navigation)
    }
}
```

I want each row to contain only three columns and at most 12 rows on a page.

Below is the html code

```
    <div class="col-md-8 products-right" id="main">

<nav class="numbering" id="navigation">
    <ul class="pagination paging">
        <li>
            <a href="#" aria-label="Previous">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">1<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" aria-label="Next">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I want to know how I can implement pagination here

Comment: I had faced a similar issue, I had implemented promises to resolve that. Here's a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49155918/7177029) to my issue, hope you find it useful. Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5L4waLx6/59/) to see it in live action.

Comment: @KunalMukherjee To be very very honest, I am having a hard time understanding the solution. What I can not understand is, what exactly makes the "input" data to go on the next page. Could you please provide and explanation?

Comment: For the first 5 rows it's wrapped inside a promise. When the 6th row comes I'm using `.trigger()` to programmatically fire the click event in the `.then()` of the promise causing it to automatically go into the 2nd page.